# How can I list only sub-directories using "ls" with absolute(full) path or achieving it wihout "ls"?

Tags: bash

I know that using `ls -d */` list only sub-directories in the current directory but I want to list with it absolute paths.

Can I achieve it?

I know just listing the any files of the current directories with absolute paths are done by typing `ls -d $PWD/*`

For instance as we are in `/home/boston/` and run `ls -d */` , we get the following sub-directories with relative paths.

```
Desktop/  Documents/  Downloads/  kl/  Music/  Pictures/  Public/  Templates/  Videos/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this is a "how to do this with `ls`" puzzle, so that non-`ls` solutions are disqualified, the normal way to do this in daily scripting would be to use the `find` utility:

```
find "$(pwd)" -type d
```

Now, that will include the current directory itself in the listing. If we have GNU find, we can use

```
find "$(pwd)" -mindepth 1 -type d
```

to prune that away, or else filter it out of the output in other ways.

GNU find's `mindepth` and `maxdepth` can restrict to just the direct subdirectories of the current directory:

```
find "$(pwd)" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Also, note I'm using the `pwd` utility, not the `PWD` variable. The utility is more reliable because it inquires the operating system kernel via the `getcwd` library function, whereas `PWD` is just a variable maintained by the shell whose value is only correct if it has been correctly maintained.

```
$ PWD=42
$ echo $PWD
42
```

`PWD` is useful in shell script fragments for customizing the personal environment, not anything that should be halfway robust under all imaginable circumstances.

`pwd` has useful options; eg with `pwd -P` you can have the path canonicalized, so it is free of symbolic links.

Comment: I changed the title of my post so that your this post is qualified here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ls -d $PWD*/
```

Comment: Sorry I meant that I want to list a sub-directories of a current directory with full paths..

Comment: typo: first 'a' should be removed .

Comment: add an extra level to their answer: `ls -d $PWD*/*/`

Comment: @tdy You are awesome.

Comment: I suggest to enable starglob in your bash to get all levels of subdirs: `shopt -s starglob; ls -d "$PWD"/**/`

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this with `ls` by just typing

`ls -d $PWD*/*/`

or

`ls -d $PWD/*/`

Comment: You don't want the `*` directly after `$PWD` (it'll make `/home/boston` potentially expand to `/home/boston` AND `/home/bostonian` and `/home/bostonglobe` AND...), and also double-quote `$PWD` in case it contains anything weird. So: `"$PWD"/*/`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of filenames, you don't actually need `ls` here; the correct glob (wildcard) expression will give a list of paths, you just need something to print them:

```
echo "$PWD"/*/    # Prints them with spaces between
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/*/    # Prints each one on a separate line
```

The main limitation with these is that if there aren't any subdirectories, they'll go ahead and print the unexpanded wildcard (e.g. "/home/boston/*/"). `ls` will actually check each one before printing it, and give you an error like "No such file or directory" if there's no match.